# List of books for the physics dummy?

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

Since physics is not an obligatory subject in most schools around the world (and mostly optional only through high school for advanced learners), it means that most people have not even a basic knowledge of physics.

Assuming that physics becomes a mandatory subject in pre college schools, what list of books (preferably short), would you recommend to include in the curriculum so that a high school graduate has some basic knowledge of physics?

Answer (score 1):

well, There are several physics books out there in market but not all of them are so much good to read and enjoyable .. moreover the field requires imagination, understanding and problem solving skills  ..... SO a good book is one which gives provides you with all..
I personally LOVE book written by prof. **HC VERMA** the "**CONCEPTS OF PHYSICS**"        this is absolutely fab book and provides you with basic understanding knowledge some proofs and great but few numerical problems.. I used this book for my IITJEE preparation
IN INDIA this book can be bought at any bookcentre but for foreigners you can get it online
The next book I referred is again one of the best books to understand physics
it is "**principles of physics**"   by resnik walker halliday        also this book provides you with plenty of questions..

ands at last if you want serious mind boggling questions with heavy maths included and imagination skill    then only reffer to "problems in general physics" by  IE IRODOV    and book by KROTOV

I expect that this would be helpful

I accept that book by irodov is using a little bit outdated english and its an old book     but physics ever remains the same  ..
GOOD LUCK

Comment: if you follow these books then follow first HCV and then resnik walker haliday